# integrate with fixed lower limit but varying upper limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to integrate a function $f(x)$ with a fixed lower limit of integration, e.g. zero, while for the upper limit I want to use a list of values, e.g. {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.

How can I make a code for this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate [f(x)dx=1dx]"? Are you looking for something like `Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, #}] & /@ Range[9]`?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose:

```
f[x_] := Exp[-x] Sinc[x]
```

Then, you could do:

```
if[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[z], {z, 0, x}]

if /@ Range[10] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.068437, {0.606074, 0.766799, 0.790501, 0.788276, 0.785869, 0.785285, 
>     0.785313, 0.78538, 0.785401, 0.785401}}

On the other hand, you could instead use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue), which will be much faster:

```
int = NDSolveValue[{g'[x] == f[x], g[0] == 0}, g, {x, 0, 10}];

int /@ Range[10] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000025, {0.606074, 0.766799, 0.790501, 0.788276, 0.785869, 0.785284, 
>     0.785313, 0.78538, 0.785401, 0.785401}}

Answer (score 1):

[`Carl Woll's`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) example can also be done analytically

```
f[x_] = Exp[-x] Sinc[x];

if[t_] = Assuming[t > 0, Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, t}]]

(* t HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4}, {1/2, 3/4, 5/4, 5/4}, -(t^4/64)] + 
 1/18 t^2 (-9 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2}, {3/4, 5/4, 3/2, 3/2}, -(t^4/64)] + 
    2 t HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4}, {5/4, 3/2, 7/4, 7/4}, -(t^4/64)]) *)

Plot[{f[x], if[x]}, {x, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.75, .475}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
if /@ Range[9] // N // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.02138, {0.606074, 0.766799, 0.790501, 0.788276, 0.785869, 0.785285,
   0.785313, 0.78538, 0.785401}} *)
```

Comment: thank you guys for help